# SQL PRINT not working in certain instance

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

In the following if I try to place a print after the BEGIN statement it doesn't work, when I remove everything within the BEGIN-END statement and place a print it does work;

```
SET @SQL = 'IF (((SELECT fldLT FROM #zArray) = ''p'') OR ((SELECT fldMF FROM #zArray) <> -1))
            BEGIN
                SET @X = '+@Z+' * ((SELECT fldLF FROM #zArray) / 100))

                IF (CAST((SELECT fldMF FROM #zArray) AS FLOAT) > '+@X+')
                    BEGIN
                        SET @X = (CAST((SELECT fldMF FROM #zArray) AS FLOAT))
                    END                         
                END'   

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@X NVARCHAR(50),@Z NVARCHAR(50)', @X, @Z
```

Is there something wrong with the following code that would cause the print statement not to work?

```
    'SET @X = '+@Z+' * ((SELECT fldLF FROM #zArray) / 100))

                IF (CAST((SELECT fldMF FROM #zArray) AS FLOAT) > '+@X+')
                    BEGIN
                        SET @X = (CAST((SELECT fldMF FROM #zArray) AS FLOAT))
END'
```

Comment: What are you trying to set `@SQL` to? I don't think `SET @var = IF...` is ever valid.. but I could be wrong. Still I can't tell what you're trying to set @SQL to either way.

Comment: I'm having trouble following your code. Most of it should be treated as a varchar (surrounded by single quotes) before you pass it to ``sp_executesql``. But the way you concatenate values and use parameters is also confusing.

Comment: My apologies forgot to add in the quotes, it is dynamic SQL, the @SQL var is NVARCHAR(MAX)... I am trying to do a PRINT N''WORKS'' after the BEGIN statement but before the SET @X variable, unfortunately it doesn't print.

Comment: Why are you using dynamic SQL here anyway? Simply doing `SET @X = @Z * ((SELECT fldLF ...` would work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand why you're concatenating your parameters and you're using them again, in the procedure `sp_executesql`.

I modified a little your query, removing the concatenation of the parameters and using the [REPLACE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx) function, to replace the placeholders with your parameters:

```
DECLARE @X NVARCHAR(50) = '123'
DECLARE  @Z NVARCHAR(50) = '123'
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @SQL = 'IF (((SELECT fldLT FROM #zArray) = ''p'') OR ((SELECT fldMF FROM #zArray) <> -1))
            BEGIN
                SET @paramX = @paramZ * ((SELECT fldLF FROM #zArray) / 100))

                IF (CAST((SELECT fldMF FROM #zArray) AS FLOAT) > @paramX)
                    BEGIN
                        SET @paramX = (CAST((SELECT fldMF FROM #zArray) AS FLOAT))
                    END                         
                END'   

SET @SQL = REPLACE(@SQL,'@paramX',@X)
SET @SQL = REPLACE(@SQL,'@paramZ',@Z)

PRINT @SQL

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
```

For me, the PRINT statement is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your need SQL Statement to passed as a string not the variable being using in the dynamic sql

```
DECLARE @Xr NVARCHAR(50) = '1000351' DECLARE  @Zr NVARCHAR(50) = '46546321'
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @SQL = 'IF (((SELECT fldLT FROM #zArray) = ''p'') OR ((SELECT fldMF FROM #zArray) <> -1))
            BEGIN
                SET @X = @Z * ((SELECT fldLF FROM #zArray) / 100))

                IF (CAST((SELECT fldMF FROM #zArray) AS FLOAT) > @X)
                    BEGIN
                        SET @X = (CAST((SELECT fldMF FROM #zArray) AS FLOAT))
                    END                         
                END '   
PRINT @SQL
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, 
                    N'@X NVARCHAR(50),@Z NVARCHAR(50)', 
                    @X = @Xr, 
                    @Z = @Zr
```

**PRINT Result**

```
IF (((SELECT fldLT FROM #zArray) = 'p') OR ((SELECT fldMF FROM #zArray) <> -1))
            BEGIN
                SET @X = 46546321 * ((SELECT fldLF FROM #zArray) / 100))

                IF (CAST((SELECT fldMF FROM #zArray) AS FLOAT) > 1000351)
                    BEGIN
                        SET @X = (CAST((SELECT fldMF FROM #zArray) AS FLOAT))
                    END                         
                END
```